# How to load image in Firefox addon sdk module?

Tags: image, html5-canvas, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk

OK so I've got this addon where I'm trying to load a bitmap from a **file:///** URI and draw it to canvas.

All that goes fine until I need to get the data off the canvas using *getImageData*, then I run into a security exception. I go to Moz Chat and am told that because I'm loading the image from a page modded HTML File, it's a cross domain policy issue and not allowed.

The solution, they say, is to go to the main module and load the image there, copy it to a canvas, then serialize the data with *getImageData* and send it back to the HTML doc. 
One problem: Jetpack doesn't know what "Image" is because it doesn't have an HTML DOM, thus the operation seems to be rendered more or less impossible.

Why is this a cross domain policy issue in the first place? Beyond that, how do I load the image without access to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The simpler and best example of communication between main.js module and a content script you can read is in [Add-on SDK docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod): look for the section under the title *Communicating With Content Scripts*.

Basically, this is how the main module tells the content script (the pagemod in your case) something:

```
worker.port.emit("getElements", tag);
```

and this is how it listens to whatever the content script tells him:

```
worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
  console.log(elementContent);
});
```

On the other side, the content script listens to what the main module says to it this way:

```
self.port.on("getElements", ...
```

And finally, a case this example is missing is how the content script may emit an event to tell something to the main module:

```
self.port.emit("myCustomEvent", var1=someValue, var2=otherValue, ...)
```

But that's the idea. I also recommend you to tale a careful look at this more general explanation about how content script (pagemods, widgets, tabs, panels, etc) work because this is the mosst important concept to understand how sdk addons work.

Last, about the cross domain issue on content scripts you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts).

Comment: Yeah that looks pretty good... since I brought it to the attention of the Mozilla devs and they restored the missing examples... After consulting with them, they disclosed the only way to load the image untainted was to load it as binary on the module side; turn it to a data URI; and pass the URI to a content script which passes it to a page script. Awful, awful setup. Most complex file loading scheme _ever_.

Comment: ...And, allow me to go ahead and down-vote you for replying without answering the question. Nevermind... don't have the rep... you're safe.